# Dividing ArrayList into smaller ArrayLists with specific amount of element

Tags: java, arraylist

I am not a programmer. I work at warehouse and I would like to make my work easier. One of my responsibilities is to divide excel file with over 2000 rows into smaller ones and send them out. I do it manually and I would like to create a program that does it for me.

I have managed to read the data from excel. Each row is put into an Item data structure. And all of them are put into ArrayList.

```
public class Item{
    String ean;
    int amount;
}
```

Here is my problem.

I have one ArrayList with over 2000 elements. Each element has String Name and int amount.

I must divide it into smaller ArrayLists but the condition is that the total amount of item.getAmount() can´t be more than 800;

```
int totalAmount = 0;
int counter = 1;
List<Item> temp = new ArrayList<>();

for (Itema item: items) {  
    totalAmount += item.getAmount();
    if (totalAmount <= 800) {
        temp.add(item);
    }
    if (counter == items.size()) {
        createFile(temp);
        temp.clear();
    }
    if (totalAmount > 800) {
       createFile(temp);
       temp.clear();
       temp.add(item);
       totalAmount = 0;
   }
   counter++;
}
```

When I run this with ArrayList that contains thirty items each with amount 100. It creates 4 excel files. First three only have 1 row each and fourth one has 4 rows.

I can't figure it out. Any suggestions??

Comment: Shouldn't you be clearing `temp` *after* you've used it in `createFile`? You're erasing the list, adding an element to it, then using the erased list to create a file.

Comment: The dupe closure isn't me saying your question is bad, it's me saying that your answer is in another castle.  I can't think of a better approach anyway than what's in that other answer.

Comment: @Makoto It's not the same question. Most of those answers are irrelevant here.

Comment: @shmosel:  I ***emphatically*** disagree.  If the issue is to partition their list of 2,000 records into N lists with up to 800 records, then the answers in that question *completely* cover the circumstance.  Maybe you're reading something I'm not here?

Comment: @Makoto But that's not the requirement. Read it again carefully.

Comment: @shmosel:  I am beyond the point of you trying to mansplain a requirement to me.  Tell me what you've seen so I can at least get some peace in knowing why you reversed what I believe to be an applicable dupe closure.

Comment: @Makoto, the requirement appears to be that the sum of the values of the `amount` properties of the `Item`s in each sublist not exceed 800.  It's not about the sizes of the sublists.

Comment: Should `totalAmount = 0;` be `totalAmount = item.getAmount();`?

Comment: Now it creates 4 files. First with 8 rows, second with  9, third with  9 and fourth with 4. I need it to be has to be 8, 8, 8, 6.

Comment: Because you're only checking after it overflows. You need to check and flush first.

Comment: Thank you for quick reactions. What do you mean by check and flush?

Comment: Check if it's going to overflow, write to file if necessary, and only then add the item.

Comment: That makes more sense then @JohnBollinger.  I withdraw my objection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it easier not to think of it in terms of adding things into a list, and then clearing it afterwards, but rather just by identifying the start and end of sublists which don't exceed the target sum (*):

```
int start = 0;
while (start < items.size()) {
  // Move the end pointer until your total exceeds 800.
  int end = start + 1;
  int totalAmount = items.get(start).getAmount();
  while (end < items.size()) {
    int amount = items.get(end).getAmount();
    if (totalAmount + amount > 800) {
      break;
    }
    totalAmount += amount;
    end++;
  }

  // Now flush the sublist between start and end:
  createFile(items.subList(start, end));

  // Now move on to the next.
  start = end;
}
```

---

(*) You may get a single-element sublist which exceeds the sum, e.g. if the amount is 801. You can't do anything with that case, other than write it by itself.

Comment: This one works, I am very thankful to you and everyone else who answered in this thread. It is going to make my work much less annoying. If I may ask one more question. What if I want each file to have maximum of 8 rows?

Comment: Change the condition on the while loop to `end < items.size() && (end - start) < 8`.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to the revised code producing sublists of length 8, 9, 9, 4, the problem is that after flushing the current sublist to a file, you reset the `totalAmount` incorrectly, not taking into account the item you are currently processing.  You end up with `temp` containing one element, but `totalAmount` being zero.

To make `totalAmount` reflect the correct sum of the `amount`s of the items in temp, that alternative should look more like this:

```
    if (totalAmount > 800) {
        createFile(temp);
        temp.clear();
        temp.add(item);                  // temp now contains one element
        totalAmount = item.getAmount();  // this is the 'amount' of that element
    }
```